# Perform XSLT Transform as Build-Step

Tags: visual-studio, xslt, msbuild, automation, transform

During a Visual Studio build, I need to have an XML file generated from another XML file.  It is obvious to me an XSLT template and transform is exactly what I need.

The way I prefer to accomplish this is to use the "Custom Tool" property found on project files.  Is there already a built-in tool I can use for this purpose?  My next option might be to use a pre-build step of the csproj.  Again, is there a (Visual Studio or MSBUILD) pre-existing or pre-installed tool that I can invoke from a pre-build step to do this?

Finally, if need be, I could have modify the .csproj file itself to add a MSbuild Task which performs the transform (I think MSBuild comes with such a Task - if not I know they are available for download).

Overall, I'd just like to know the easiest way to get this done, and how to do it.  I already know how to write XSL templates. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're using VS2010 you can use the built-in [`XslTransformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff598688.aspx) task of MSBuild 4 in a post build step.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <XslTransformation
    XslInputPath="transform.xslt"
    XmlInputPaths="in.xml"
    OutputPaths="out.xml" />
</Target>
```

Comment: This is what I had concluded over the weekend. :)

Comment: Do the "debug" and "optimization" settings in a web.config alter the way the build occurs or are they only used when compiling/pre-compiling the site? I ask just to make sure that transformations shouldn't occur before the build begins.

Comment: My next comment will be how to code "Parameters", since that was tricky

Comment: <XslTransformation
        XslInputPath="$(ProjectDir)MyXsl.xsl"
        XmlInputPaths="$(ProjectDir)MyInputXml.xml"
        OutputPaths="$(ProjectDir)MyOutputXml.xml" 
        Parameters="&lt;Parameter Name='MyParameterOne' Value='MyValueOne'/&gt;"
 />

Comment: @granadaCoder How you figured that out from the VS documentation is beyond my comprehension.

Comment: You're right.  That was some serious voodoo right there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally go with installing the [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) and invoking msbuild.exe from the PostBuild Event in the project settings.

A shudder just went down my spine at the thought of XSLT files too!  :P

Comment: I will install MSBuild Community Tasks if I must (I use those in other circumstances), but I'm really hoping to find an already-installed tool that fits the need.

Comment: In that case if you're using VS2010 you could use the config transforms stuff... but that really just works on deply AFAIK